# Draw lines between two known points

Tags: delphi, gmlib

Using Delphi XE3 and GMLib 1.2.4.  Should be basic question.  How to draw basic non-linked lines between two given points.  I currently have GMMap displayed on a WebBrowser and have GMPolyline component.  Using known values for both lat-lon pairs.  Just need help plotting line between the two.  Using this to plot lines of bearing.  This is what I have so far:

```
procedure TMainGMForm.ButtonPlotLineClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  CurLat,CurLon,DisLat,DisLon: Double;
  P1,P2: TLatLng;
begin
  CurLat := StrToFloat(EditLat.Text);
  CurLon := StrToFloat(EditLon.Text);
  DisLat := StrToFloat(EditLat2.Text);
  DisLon := StrToFloat(EditLon2.Text);
  P1 := TLatLng.Create(CurLat,CurLon);
  Inc(PointIndex);
  P2 := TLatLng.Create(DisLat,DisLon);
  Inc(PointIndex);
  //what goes here to plot a line between these two points? 
  // 
  FreeAndNil(P1);
  FreeAndNil(P2);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a TPolyline into your TGMPolyline, something like this

```
var
  Poly: TPolyline;
begin
  Poly := TPolyline(GMPolyline1.Add);
```

and add the two points into the LinePoints array

```
  Poly.AddLinePoint(CurLat, CurLon);
  Poly.AddLinePoint(DisLat, Double);
```